# Checking conflicting data with SELECT and IF statements in a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am using the SELECT statement to select the conflicting treatments from the prescription table that i have and the i am using an IF statement to check the selected data against the data that i am entering when running the procedure. What i expect this procedure to do is disallow the same client to book conflicting treatments on the same day. But when i run my procedure i am getting an error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". If i run the select statement on its own, it works as explained above. Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2,
    FP_DATE DATE)
AS
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
   V_P_DATE PRESCRIPTION.P_DATE%TYPE;
   V_TREAT_ID TREATMENTS.TREAT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT P.CLIENT_ID, T.CONFLICT, P.P_DATE, T.TREAT_ID
    INTO V_CLIENT_ID, V_CONFLICT, V_P_DATE, V_TREAT_ID
    FROM PRESCRIPTION P, TREATMENTS T
    WHERE P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID
    AND T.CONFLICT IS NOT NULL;

    IF FP_DATE = V_P_DATE AND FCLIENT_ID = V_CLIENT_ID AND FTREAT_ID = V_TREAT_ID THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID, P_DATE)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID, FP_DATE);
    END IF;
END FPRESC;
/
```

and an example of the data i am trying to enter for new prescription (note: this data is conflicting, so it should throw an error when entered):

```
 EXEC FPRESC ('P00011', 'T016', 'C00017', 'D006', '28-NOV-14');
```

Some insight would be much appreciated, if possible

Comment: I would strongly suspect that your `select` statement is returning multiple rows.  It's not clear to me whether you are saying that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

"exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" is a pretty clear message, and probably refers to your select statement. Using `select ... into` your query must return exactly one row, because you only specify one set of variables. This message suggests that your query returns more than one row.

I think the best solution would be to do the checks in the query itself. Then you can return wether or not the query matches anything (in which case there is a conflict). This query will always return exactly one record with a 1 or 0 indicated a conflict or not, even if the subquery that does the checks returns more than 1 conflict.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT 'X'
        FROM 
          PRESCRIPTION P
          INNER JOIN TREATMENTS T ON T.TREAT_ID = P.TREAT_ID
        WHERE 
          FP_DATE = P.P_DATE 
          AND FCLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID 
          AND FTREAT_ID = T.TREAT_ID 
          AND T.CONFLICT IS NOT NULL) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
    END
INTO
    V_EXISTS
FROM DUAL;

IF V_EXISTS = 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Conflict'); -- Actual exception, if you like
ELSE
    INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID, P_DATE)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID, FP_DATE);
END IF;
```

By the way, if you need to read more than one row from a query, you can either open it as a cursor, to process it one by one. Use a [for loop](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php) for easy access.

Or you can use [bulk collect into](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_bulk_collect.htm) to read all the data into a single table-like variable.

Comment: not sure why, as this query seems valid, but as i enter the conflicting data it still adds it to the table without errors